# How to set validation rule: "Task start date >= Project start date" in MS access

Tags: vba, database, validation, ms-access, rules

I'm looking to set up validation rules for MS Access, the "project start date" is located in "projects" table while the "task start date" is located in "task" table. I want to set the rule in my form textbox so that "The task should not start earlier than the project"

I would like to set the validation rule in forms but I am clueless as how to construct this inter-table validation rule via "expression builder" or "VBA code builder".

Could someone with knowledge in this help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Use `DLOOKUP()` function then compare those two date.

Comment: Hi! Do I have to write any additional arguments to specify which record to lookup ? Let say I'm filling out "Task A" for "Project A" and I want the validation rule to kick in and verify it with the data in "Project A"

Comment: `DLOOKUP()` has `Criteria` you can use if needed to retrieve value from particular record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in pictures, and assuming that since Project must come before task we have a 1 to many relationship (use the relationships tab) like:

[image]

then clicking on the projects table and clicking create form we get a form with subform already built like:

[image]

(some textboxes and labels already deleted for prettification)

Click on the TaskStartDate TextBox and under properties select the validation rule.

Here is where you put the DLOOKUP

```
[TaskStartDate]>DLookUp("ProjectStartDate","Projects","ProjectID = " & [ProjectID])
```

We can access TaskStartDate and ProjectID because the subform is based on the tasks table(which is why we need to set up the relationship and put the ProjectID in the Tasks table), but we have to look up the corresponding ProjectStartDate using ProjectID

Comment: Hi there, can I ask what are the prerequisites required for this expression to work? I have tried inputting [Task Start] > DLookUp("Project Start", "Project", "Project Name = " & [Project Name])

I have replaced Project ID with Project Name as that's my primary key for the table, my Task Name is also my primary key in the other table.

Comment: the expression works as is if you have the same table and form structure I show in the answer.  check for a mistake in translating the answer to your case.  if it helps: TaskStartDate is how Access autonamed the textbox controlled by TaskStartDate, that might have tricked you.  Maybe check to see what the record source is for the form and subform and how they are bound.  Consider putting the solution in a blank database, getting the solution to work, then  compare and contrast with your database.

Comment: so [TaskStartDate] is the textbox, "ProjectStartDate", "Projects", & "ProjectID" refer to the columns in the Projects Table.  [ProjectID] is the value of ProjectID in the currently selected row of the subforms recordsource.